# which is the valid firefox binary path for python tbselenium?

Tags: python, selenium, tor

Actually I am having the extracted file in `C:/tor/` and another folder is in Desktop. And I am trying with the following code

```
import tbselenium.common as cm
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
from tbselenium.utils import launch_tbb_tor_with_stem
tbb_dir = 'C:/Users/myName/Desktop/Tor Browser/'
tor_process = launch_tbb_tor_with_stem(tbb_path=tbb_dir)
with TorBrowserDriver(tbb_dir) as driver:
    driver.load_url("https://check.torproject.org")

tor_process.kill()
```

But I am getting `tbselenium.exceptions.StemLaunchError: Invalid Tor binary` I don't what is the path I have to specify, I tried the following paths

```
C:/Users/myName/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/
C:/Users/myName/Desktop/Tor Browser/Browser/firefox.exe
C:/tor/Browser/firefox.exe
C:/tor/Browser/
C:/tor
```

for the all above path I am getting the same error. I don't know how to specify the path for tbselenium

Comment: I tried it but no luck. I tried with backward slashes also. I tried with `r'path/'` also :(

Comment: My best two guesses would be to either: 1) leave tbb_path unset, and set `tor_binary` to the full path of the firefox.exe bin (otherwise, the function would concat the strings), or 2) set tbb_path = "...\Tor Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Tor", but unset tor_binary

Answer (score 1):

I hope, that this answer will help you.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from itertools import cycle

from seleniumwire import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 

socks=["178.62.193.19","176.9.75.42","120.132.52.180"]

ports=[8080,3128,8888]

socks_ports={}

socks_ports=dict(zip(socks,ports))

socks_pool=cycle(socks_ports.keys())

ports_pool=cycle(socks_ports.values())

def ChangeProxy(ProxyHost,ProxyPort):

    options = {

    'proxy': {

        'http': 'http://username:password@'+str(ProxyHost)+':'+str(ProxyPort),

        'https': 'https://username:password@'+str(ProxyHost)+':'+str(ProxyPort),

        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'

        }

    }

    return webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)

while True:

    socks_item=next(socks_pool)

    ports_item=next(ports_pool)

    print(type(socks_item))

    print(type(ports_item))


    try:
        driver=ChangeProxy(socks_item,ports_item)

        driver.get("https://www.ipchicken.com/")
    except:
        continue
```

P.S.
I have tried many times and its work. You should try to find hosts and ports and add to arrays above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try it out. :)

Comment: I don't know why, but this is very unstable code. I wrote it yesterday by myself. If you can improve it, it will be great. I think if you want that this code be stable, you should by proxies. But rotation works sometimes, sometimes Firefox get error 502 bad request.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution is to manually proxy your selenium driver and use firefox.  I have seen a lot of questions about the `tbselenium` package, so I'm starting to think it doesn't work.

This should do the trick, assuming you have a tor instance (not the browser) running and have successfully configured the `geckodriver` for selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks", "127.0.0.1")
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_port", 9050)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_version", 5)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get("http://whatismyip.com")
```

Also, if you need help starting a tor instance (not the browser) on Windows just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am pretty sure I found the answer [here](https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium/issues/107):

Windows is not supported!